# visual studio / asp.net bug or normal?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

While I'm programming, sometimes everything gets this red underline like everything is wrong or missing something suddenly!

What is happening?

[Red Underline Error - Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JI9O.png)

Comment: Look at the errors, it could be a missing closing bracket or something similar. views are not compiled by default so a bad view will not stop you building the project.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code itself.. I had to close and reopen visual studio. idk why but works fine now.